# Perforce Code Review Integration for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, code-review, perforce

Currently our team uses **Code Collaborator** for remote Code Reviews and **Perforce** (Helix) for Source Control. We work primarily in **C++ in Visual Studio 2017**.

I believe our remote code review process could be greatly improved by performing Code Reviews directly in the Visual Studio project they were written in. This would allow reviewers to easily see the entire code base, get syntax highlighting, Intellisense hints/navigation and more.

Something along the lines of "Team Explorer" in Visual Studio, which allows you to review your changes right in VS prior to pushing a change to a Repo.

However, I have not been able to find anything that meets these needs.

Review Assistant (https://www.devart.com/review-assistant/) appears to be *exactly* what I am looking for, but does not support P4 fully (you can only review a change *after* it was submitted, which is a deal breaker for us).

I would love to get some suggestions on how to fullfill these requirements!

Thanks!